# Trying to request api call with html button

Tags: node.js, html-framework-7

I'm trying to use this html button to call the api but is not working properly.

```
<button class="col button button-fill" onclick="weather()">Get Weather</button>

<script> unirest.get("https://weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com/current?
lang=en&lon=<required>&lat=<required>")
.header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com")
.header("X-RapidAPI-Key","02f2e99835msh60df6f30e23585dp137d84jsn437639993023")
.end(function (result) { console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);});</script>
```

Comment: Define "Not working properly". But from the information you've given, you gotta wrap the get request in a function. Like this: `function weather(){unirest.get().header().header().end()}`

Comment: I'm using this code <script>
        function weather() {
  // Your javascript code to bring data from database. 
}
         unirest.get("https://weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com/current?lang=en&lon=<required>&lat=<required>")
.header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com")
.header("X-RapidAPI-Key", "02f2e99835msh60df6f30e23585dp137d84jsn437639993023")
.end(function (result) {
  console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);
});
        
        
        </script>

Comment: But what's the problem that your'e having, what have you tried. Saying something "is not working properly" doesn't help us understand your issue.

Comment: I second the above comment. Exactly result do you expect which you are not seeing?

Answer (score 0):

You are simply making the request when the script is loaded. There is no calling to it. When the button is pressed it is referencing a weather() function which you have not shown us. I'm assuming the given code within the script is what you want to run when the button is clicked. To do that you need to put it within a function which is triggered by the onclick. So something like this:

```
<script>
function weather(){
    unirest.get("https://weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com/currentlang=en&lon=<required>&lat=<required>")
    .header("X-RapidAPI-Host", "weatherbit-v1-mashape.p.rapidapi.com")
    .header("X-RapidAPI-Key","02f2e99835msh60df6f30e23585dp137d84jsn437639993023")
    .end(function (result) { console.log(result.status, result.headers, result.body);});
}
</script>
```

The onclick in the button tag looks for a function which is put in the quotes, it doesn't create one for you.

Comment: This is the button I created: <button class="col button button-fill" onclick="weather()">Get Weather </button> So when I use the script it does not do anything and no api is called. Any other suggestions to make the button work when is click?

Comment: @EduardoRamirez that should work. Check your console.